# Recursively find all files from a folder containing a regexp in the filename, using helm

Tags: helm, search

How can I find all files from a folder and its subfolders recursively, containing a regexp in the filename, using helm?

For example: how to search for all files with the extension `.el` and containing the string `dired` in the directory `emacs-24.3` its subdirectories, using helm?

Comment: [Meta discussion about the wording of this question](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/115/should-question-text-restate-the-title)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On systems that provide GNU `find` utility, you can use `helm-find` (by default bound to `C-x c /`) to get the desired behavior. Starting `helm-find` with a prefix argument `C-u C-x c /` prompts for the directory (`emacs24.3` in the example) first and then for the pattern (`dired el` in the example). Without the prefix argument, it uses the default directory of the current buffer.

EDIT: Note that `helm-find` cannot use wildcards or regexps unlike the actual `find` utility. It does however support a whitespace separator to match multiple pattern within a string. For instance `dired .el` matches only filenames that contain both the strings `dired` and `.el` in the path in any order.

Answer (score 5):

This answer isn't exactly what you want (it does not use helm and does not use
regexp) but Emacs has a built-in command called `find-name-dired` which finds
recursively in a directory all files matching a given [shell wildcard](http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html) and
opens a Dired buffer with all the matching files.

For your particular example you can do

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-name-dired` <kbd>RET</kbd> `/path/to/emacs-24.3` <kbd>RET</kbd> `*.el` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about using Helm, you can do what you ask using [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles).

What is it that you want to do with the files you find?  Open them? Search them? I'll assume you want to open them, as an illustration.

Here are a couple different ways. The first is simpler; the second shows some additional features that you can also use in other ways.

---

1. Use [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) **`icicle-locate-file-other-window`** to open files under a given directory, matching them by name or content, or both. You are prompted for the directory within which to look.  (On platforms that have system command `locate` you can use `icicle-locate` instead, which is faster than `icicle-locate-file`.)

   Then type a [multi-completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) pattern to match.  For example:

   ```
   f.* C-M-j some text .*in the file
   ```

   The files with *names* matching regexp **`f.*`** and with *content* matching regexp **`some text .*in the file`** are the completion candidates. Each part here is optional: if you want, you can filter on just file names or just file contents. The matching (absolute) file names appear in buffer `*Completions*`.

   **`C-M-j`** here is a multi-completion separator.  (Helm uses a space similarly, but in **Icicles** space chars are often used in the patterns themselves, which can be any regexps.  Actually, what is used for the separator is defined by a user option.)

   Optionally, hit **`S-SPC`** and then type more patterns to narrow the completion choices further.  You can use `S-SPC` to add as many patterns as you like.  This is [progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion).

   Type **`C-!`** to open all of the candidate files.

   Without exiting multi-command `icicle-locate-file-other-window`, you can change the filtering expressions to get a different subset of the file names, and then act on them as well.  However, if you accumulated patterns using progressive completion, then any patterns you entered before the last `S-SPC` are locked in, unless you use [**`C-x C-0`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets#RecompletingUsingTheOriginalDomain) to restore the original domain of candidates (which in this case is all of the files under the given directory).

---

2. With the second approach, you first *save the names of all files in and below the current directory*.  You can save that list in a cache file, in an Emacs fileset, or in a variable.  If you want to save it in a variable, you can be prompted for it or just use the default variable for this, `icicle-saved-completion-candidates`.

   You can do this in Dired using command `icicle-dired-save-marked-recursive`.  If you use library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus) then this command is bound to **`M-+ C-M->`**.

   (`M-+` is a **Dired+** prefix for acting on all files under a directory, or all marked files there and in marked subdirs, defined recursively.  `C-M->` is the standard **Icicles** completion action key for saving candidates.)

   You can later retrieve the list of file names (as many times as you like), to act on the files themselves.  When you do this, you can filter the files - by name or by content, using one or more regexps or substrings.

   For example, if you want to open all of the files (among those whose *names* were saved) whose names match `f.*` and whose *content* matches `some text .*in the file`, then do this:

   ```
     C-u C-x 4 C-f C-M-< f.* C-M-j some text .*in the file C-!
   ```

   Decomposing that:

   - **`C-x 4 C-f`** is **Icicles** command `icicle-file-other-window`, which is a [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) version of `find-file-other-window`.  But with **`C-u`** the candidates are *absolute* file names.  (The names saved using `M-+ C-M->`, which you are going to retrieve, are absolute, as they are in different directories.)
   - **`C-M-<`** is the opposite of `C-M->`.  It *retrieves* a saved set of files (by default, from variable `icicle-saved-completion-candidates`).
   - Just as in the first method, `f.* C-M-j some text .*in the file` says to match regexp `f.*` against file *names* and match regexp `some text .*in the file` against the file *contents*.  This filters the set of file names to those that satisfy these two constraints.
   - **`C-!`** means *act on all* candidates.  The action here is to find (open) the file.

   As with the first method, without exiting multi-command `icicle-file-other-window`, you can change the filtering expressions to get a different subset of the saved file names, and then act on them as well.