# Helm: helm-find-files: how find files recursive?

Tags: helm, microsoft-windows

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

If I want to find file in Helm I use command `helm-find-files`. 
Suppose I want to find in current folder all files with extenstion ***.gradle**.

Here result:

[image: Find all files with extension gradle in current folder]

OK. It's work.

But now I want to find all files with extension ***.gradle** not only in current folder, but also in all subfolders (recursive). How I can do this by command `helm-find-files`?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/713/recursively-find-all-files-from-a-folder-containing-a-regexp-in-the-filename-us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively find all files from a folder containing a regexp in the filename, using helm](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/713/recursively-find-all-files-from-a-folder-containing-a-regexp-in-the-filename-us)

Answer (score 7):

Just type `TAB`, input `shell` and `RET` use `Find shell command` to find files with filename recursively.

Or simply `C-c /`

Comment: Strange name for an action. It probably should read, "Find files using `find`" or something.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this with `helm-find-files`, you could do it with `helm-find`. `helm-find` has the same fuzzy match but searches the directories recursively. It is smart in avoiding some not useful files / directories (like `.git/` etc).

Just make sure you have find program installed on your machine. It comes by default on Unix based machines. On Windows, have git bash installed. Set Git bash to your default  shell and then set the complete path of find to `find-program` variable in your `.emacs` file.

If you want to search from your `default-directory`. The standard shortcut is: `C-x c /`.

If you want to parameterize it with a different directory:

`C-u C-x c /`
`<The directory to start search from> <RET>`
`<Your search string>`

Comment: the second keybinding shd read `C-u C-x c /`.

Comment: @mooseface, Thank you. Edited with the fix.

Comment: I want to create a function that uses helm-find-files or helm-find in a specific directory recursively. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want:

```lisp
(defun my/helm-find-file-recursively ()  
  (interactive)
  "Recursively find files in glob manner, in the specified directory."
  (helm-find 'ask-for-dir))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c o f") 'my/helm-find-file-recursively)
```

Comment: Isn't this what is available out of the box? `C-u C-x c /`. See the [other answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59704/7036)